# How to query the results of 1-hour frequency data with the filling function at 1-minute frequency in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

My measuring point data in Apache IoTDB is stored at a 1-hour frequency now. I want to know how can I query the data results with a function that replenish the stored data at a 1-minute frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `select avg(power) from root.wf01 group by([2023-11-14T00:00:00,2023-11-15T00:00:00),1m) fill(linear)` command in Apache IoTDB to query the result of filling results in 1 minute frequency.